# Python GridSearchCV creating NPV custom scorer

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

I want to create the `Negative Predictive Value (NPV)` metric to evaluate Data inside a `gridsearchCV`.
I prepared an example with the iris dataset.

```py
from sklearn import svm, datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data 
target = iris.target 
names = iris.target_names
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['species'] = iris.target
#df['species'] = df['species'].replace(to_replace= [0, 1, 2], value = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'])
indexNames = df[ df['species'] == 2 ].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
x_data = pd.DataFrame({'sepal length': df[df.columns[0]],
    'sepal width': df[df.columns[1]],
    'petal length': df[df.columns[2]],
    'petal width': df[df.columns[3]]})
y_data = pd.DataFrame(df['species']).astype(float)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.5)

parameters = {
    'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'),
     'C':[1, 10]
     }
svc = svm.SVC()
scoring = ['accuracy']
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc, 
                           param_grid=parameters, 
                           scoring=scoring, 
                           refit='accuracy', 
                           n_jobs=-1, 
                           cv=kfold, 
                           verbose=0)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
grid_result
print(f'best precision score train set {grid_result.best_score_:.4f}')
print(f'best hyperparameters{grid_result.best_params_}')
print(f'precision score test set{grid_search.score(x_test, y_test):.4f}')
```

Unfortunately the exemplaric code is not working, accuracy is always 1. Thats one issue i got when i adapted my real code to an example with iris data.
Another Code works, but its for accuracy only and i need a binary classifier for metrics like precision or NPV.

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV, cross_val_score
iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}

svc = svm.SVC()
scoring = ['accuracy']
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc, 
                           param_grid=parameters, 
                           scoring=scoring, 
                           refit='accuracy', 
                           n_jobs=-1, 
                           cv=kfold, 
                           verbose=0)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
print(f'best accuracy score {grid_result.best_score_:.4f}')
print(f'best hyperparameters{grid_result.best_params_}')
print(f'accuracy score{grid_search.score(iris.data, iris.target):.4f}')
```

To sum up, whys is the first code block not working like intended and how would an implementation with the metric NPV look like?
Ideas are welcome.

Also, in other classification tasks, I wrote columns with my predicted value and I could compute `TP`, `FP`, `TN`, and `FN` directly and got my metrics. Inside the `gridCV` I couldn't figure out how to access the predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code above, the data is really well separated. To remove doubts, print the [confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn-metrics-confusion-matrix) in it, you can see that this is so.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_pred = grid_search.best_estimator_.predict(x_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

Output

```
[[22  0]
 [ 0 28]]
```

As for custom criteria, you can use: [make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer). In which the `custom_scorer` function is fed, which considers what you want. I took the `confusion_matrix` and extracted the values from it to calculate the score. What she thinks, namely the formula, you need to check, because I can be wrong.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer


def custom_scorer(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
    cnm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

    return cnm[1, 1] / (cnm[1, 1] + cnm[0, 1])


mysc = make_scorer(custom_scorer, greater_is_better=True)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc,
                           param_grid=parameters,
                           scoring=mysc,
                           refit='accuracy',
                           n_jobs=-1,
                           cv=kfold,
                           verbose=0)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```